# Simple URI and local path use in MediaPlayer-javaFX

Tags: java, media-player, javafx

I have the following code to display the spectrum of audio.But it uses URI.But how to use simple paths like C:/abc/asas.wav ...or something?Any idea?
It gives me Exception when i use local paths:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.access$000(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Code:

```
package chartaudiobar;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.chart.BarChart;
import javafx.scene.chart.CategoryAxis;
import javafx.scene.chart.NumberAxis;
import javafx.scene.chart.XYChart;
import javafx.scene.media.AudioSpectrumListener;
import javafx.scene.media.Media;
import javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class ChartAudioBar extends Application {

    private XYChart.Data<String, Number>[] series1Data;
    private AudioSpectrumListener audioSpectrumListener;

    private static final String AUDIO_URI = System.getProperty("demo.audio.url","http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/products/javafx/oow2010-2.flv");
    private static MediaPlayer audioMediaPlayer;
    private static final boolean PLAY_AUDIO = Boolean.parseBoolean(System.getProperty("demo.play.audio","true"));

    private void init(Stage primaryStage) {
        Group root = new Group();
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        root.getChildren().add(createChart());
        audioSpectrumListener = new AudioSpectrumListener() {
            @Override public void spectrumDataUpdate(double timestamp, double duration,
                    float[] magnitudes, float[] phases) {
                for (int i = 0; i < series1Data.length; i++) {
                    series1Data[i].setYValue(magnitudes[i] + 60);
                }
            }
        };
    }

    public void play() {
        this.startAudio();
    }

    @Override public void stop() {
        this.stopAudio();
    }

    protected BarChart<String, Number> createChart() {
        final CategoryAxis xAxis = new CategoryAxis();
        final NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis(0,50,10);
        final BarChart<String,Number> bc = new BarChart<String,Number>(xAxis,yAxis);
        bc.setId("barAudioDemo");
        bc.setLegendVisible(false);
        bc.setAnimated(false);
        bc.setBarGap(0);
        bc.setCategoryGap(1);
        bc.setVerticalGridLinesVisible(false);
        // setup chart
        bc.setTitle("Live Audio Spectrum Data");
        xAxis.setLabel("Frequency Bands");
        yAxis.setLabel("Magnitudes");
        yAxis.setTickLabelFormatter(new NumberAxis.DefaultFormatter(yAxis,null,"dB"));
        // add starting data
        XYChart.Series<String,Number> series1 = new XYChart.Series<String,Number>();
        series1.setName("Data Series 1");
        //noinspection unchecked
        series1Data = new XYChart.Data[128];
        String[] categories = new String[128];
        for (int i=0; i<series1Data.length; i++) {
            categories[i] = Integer.toString(i+1);
            series1Data[i] = new XYChart.Data<String,Number>(categories[i],50);
            series1.getData().add(series1Data[i]);
        }
        bc.getData().add(series1);
        return bc;
    }

     private void startAudio() {
        if (PLAY_AUDIO) {
            getAudioMediaPlayer().setAudioSpectrumListener(audioSpectrumListener);
            getAudioMediaPlayer().play();
        }
    }

    private void stopAudio() {
        if (getAudioMediaPlayer().getAudioSpectrumListener() == audioSpectrumListener) {
            getAudioMediaPlayer().pause();
        }
    }

    private static MediaPlayer getAudioMediaPlayer() {
        if (audioMediaPlayer == null) {
            Media audioMedia = new Media(AUDIO_URI);
            audioMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(audioMedia);
        }
        return audioMediaPlayer;
    }


    @Override public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        init(primaryStage);
        primaryStage.show();
        play();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) { launch(args); }
}
```

So how to use local paths here?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, i used this:

```
File file = new File("C:\\abc\\asas.wav");
audio = new Media(file.toURI().toURL().toString());
audioMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(audio);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can convert path to URI by adding protocol

C:/abc/asas.wav will be file:/C:/abc/asas.wav in Your example

Answer (score 0):

It’s 4 years after Jyoti Shaw posted this question, how to use a local music file in class ChartAudioBar. Wafu has the answer on his webpage https://osu.ppy.sh/forum/p/4629060  Look about halfway down on the page, under his heading “Frequency spectrum” and click on “Code” to see the source code. 
Wafu’s solution is similar to that of Sam de Meyer in his answer above.

//We don't need this line, because we need to use a local music file.

//private static final String AUDIO_URI = System.getProperty("demo.audio.url","http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/products/javafx/oow2010-2.flv");

```
    private static MediaPlayer audioMediaPlayer;
```

//We don't need this as well as it's equally useless as previous thing.

//private static final boolean PLAY_AUDIO = Boolean.parseBoolean(System.getProperty("demo.play.audio","true"));

//We anyway need output of the default chart, so let's say we'll put it to file data.txt, hence the 'import java.io.File' needs to be added to imports.

```
   private static File filedata = new File("data.txt");
```

// *****************************************************************************

```
    private static MediaPlayer getAudioMediaPlayer() {
        if (audioMediaPlayer == null) {
```

//We need code below, but I commented it anyway to show the difference, we need a local file, so this won't work.

//Media audioMedia = new Media(AUDIO_URI);

//So we create a local file, for example mp3.mp3 in current folder, it can be anything you want.

//File audiofile = new File("mp3.mp3");

```
        File audiofile = new File("C:/music/SummerMix.mp3");
```

//Now we need to make audioMedia as it was previously - So it needs to be URI, which .toURI() ensures easily, but as well as that, it needs a string URI, so .toString() will ensure this.

```
        Media audioMedia = new Media(audiofile.toURI().toString());
        audioMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(audioMedia);
     }
        return audioMediaPlayer;
     }
```